# How to express "implies" in ScalaCheck, say, "if an integer n * n = 0 then n = 0"?

Tags: scala, syntax, scalacheck

I would like to use Scala's property-based testing tool ScalaCheck to express a property

```
if an integer n * n = 0 then n = 0
```

How can I write this property in ScalaCheck? I know for example

```
val myprop = forAll {(n: Int) => n + 1 - 1 = n}
```

But I do not know how to express "A implies B" in ScalaCheck (without reducing it to Not-A or B, which can look clumsy).

Comment: Won't this work? `forAll {(n: Int) => n * n == 0 && n == 0}`

Comment: Alternatively: `forAll { (n: Int) => if (n * n == 0) n == 0 else true }`.  If you wanted to express an "if and only if" property, you could express that as `forAll { (n: Int) => (n * n == 0) == (n == 0) }`

Answer (score 1):

Use `==>` (implication operator)

```scala
val prop = forAll { n: Int =>
  (n * n == 0) ==> n == 0
}
```

(see their [User Guide](https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck/blob/main/doc/UserGuide.md) )
the catch is: in this particular example the condition is very hard to satisfy so ScalaCheck will give up after several tries (but at least it does tell you so, otherwise you get a false positive because your necessary condition was never checked). In that case you can provide a custom generator so that it will generate values that satisfy your condition.